# Se desactiva el gps, cada cierto tiempo en android 7

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

Se desactiva el gps, cada cierto tiempo en android 7 nougat en un Sony Xperia, estoy usando la API de fusión de google. Tengo un servicio corriendo en segundo plano.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    buildClient();

    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    wakeLock.acquire();
    if (scanHandler == null) {
        new pro().execute();
    }
    return Service.START_STICKY;

}

protected synchronized void buildClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(scan_interval_ms);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(scan_interval_ms);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    createLocationRequest();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            Log.v(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void removeUpdateLocation()
{
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable final Bundle bundle) {

    Log.i(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}
```

En android API 23 (6.0) Marshmallow funciona correctamente y en versiones anteriores.

Utilizando la Api de Android ocurre igual (se desactiva el GPS para la versión indicada).

Answer (score -1):

El problema radica en las limitaciones que se agregaron en las nuevas versiones de android para los servicios en segundo plano. Lo que se busca es que las aplicaciones optimicen mejor el uso de recursos para evitar que ciertas aplicaciones abusen de procesos que pueden gastar muchos recursos como red de datos moviles o bateria. Esto se describe mejor, en el siguiente articulo

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html

Como se menciona en el  articulo, para evitar este problema debes user un Foreground service en vez de un background service y asi deberia funcionar correctamente en todas las apis.

Para usar un servicio en foreground puedes revisar este articulo

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

en la seccion **Running a service in the foreground**

Comment: ¿En donde menciona que para Android 7 se puede desconectar? Lo que mencionas aquí aplica para todas las versiones.

Comment: no entiendo tu comentario. Los cambios que te menciono se implementaron en versiones de android 7.1 en adelante si mal no recuerdo y eso incluye la limitacion de servicios en segundo plano, permisos especiales entre otras cosas. La solucion la describo arriba.

Comment: por ejemplo permisos especiales es en 6.0.